# Qt Query Top Number Record Selecting

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt

I have a query that should request the top X number of records using the Qt framework to actually make the request to the SQL database. I have verified when I place an hard-coded number the query is successful, but when I attempt to bind to it I get an error.

```
query.prepare("SELECT TOP :numberToSelect"
              "    deviceId"
              "    , latitude"
              "    , longitude"
              "    , [timeStamp]"
              "    FROM Positions "
              "    WHERE [address] = ''"
              "    ORDER BY [timeStamp] DESC");
query.bindValue(":numberToSelect", numberMissing);
```

The variable numberMissing is an unsigned short which is passed in. Upon execution I receive this error:

> Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.  QODBC3: Unable
>   to execute statement" "SELECT TOP ?    deviceId    , latitude    ,
>   longitude    , [timeStamp]    FROM Positions     WHERE [address] = '' 
>   ORDER BY [timeStamp] DESC"

I do not see what the error would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a [select top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) with a variable, the top value needs to be in parenthesis.

Try this:

```
query.prepare("SELECT TOP (:numberToSelect)"
              "    deviceId"
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle parameters are signified with a preceding `:` - SQLServer's closest equivalent would be an `@` sign. Try changing `:numberToSelect` to `@numberToSelect`.

Comment: I'm using Qt, which supports Oracle style parameters.